# swiftUI detect app termination while in background

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an application that runs in the background capturing the user's location using CoreLocation. I want to save the data when the app is closed by the user.

When the app goes to the background, I can use the `scenePhase`, but how to detect that the application will be terminated when it's running in the background?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { phase in
                    print(scenePhase)
                })
        }
    }
}
```

this prints:

```
inactive
background
```

I have also tried the NotificationCenter

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: .main) 
{ _ in
    print("terminated")
}
```

and this is also not called when the app is already in the background.

Comment: This isn't something you should handle in a view. It is something that you should handle in your model or location manager object.

Comment: I agree, it’s not handled in the view. The problem is how to get notified when the app is about to be terminated while in the background though

Comment: `willTerminate` is the method you need to use, however this method is not called when the user "swipes up" on the app. There is no method that is guaranteed to execute in all instances of app termination.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for applicationWillTerminate:

> For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in that case.

And from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background:

> Use deactivation to preserve the user’s data and put your app in a quiet state by pausing all major work; specifically:
> Save user data to disk and close any open files.

Basically, when your app is deactivated and backgrounded, you won’t know if the app eventually gets terminated, so you probably need to use the deactivation/backgrounding to do your work, if that makes sense in your use case. Can you save the user data every time you get a location event in the background?

Comment: Thank you for the help. That would work, but it's not a good solution if you persist data every 1-2 seconds on the disk. Atm I have a buffer to extend the saves to once a minute, but I was searching for a more robust solution

Comment: This is the right approach; it shouldn't matter if you write once per minute or once per second; you just write the outstanding data, but If you keep all of the data then just write the data as it arrives and you don't really need to worry about termination. If  you are recoding location once per minute maybe accept that you might get a last location of 59 seconds ago if the app is terminated right before you were to write the next location.

Comment: Use significant location changes if you don’t really need every little change. That would definitely save on the number of writes you need to do. Otherwise, especially if you are only saving locally, just write your changes every time you get a location update.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didDiscardSceneSessions:(NSSet<UISceneSession *> *)sceneSessions;`

Comment: this doesn't work in the background. You get a notification when the app enters the background, but not when it's terminated

Comment: @georgeok this is an instance method of AppDelegate, not a notification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/3197906-application